# MFSideMenu making my status bar black?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using MFSideMenu without any difficulties. I don't load it until the user taps the menu button. When it loads, my status bar goes to black text.

This is part of the code on each view controller I'm using to color the navController and make the text white, however once I've loaded in MFSideMenu it doesn't work.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Code I use when menu button tapped to lazily load in the class:

```
+ (void)showMenuFromButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app trackScreenNamed:@"Menu"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)app.window.rootViewController;

    if (![app.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[MFSideMenuContainerViewController class]]) {
        app.window.rootViewController = nil;
        MenuController *menuController = [navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuController"];

        MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                        containerWithCenterViewController:navigationController
                                                        leftMenuViewController:menuController
                                                        rightMenuViewController:nil];
        [container setMenuWidth:262];

        app.window.rootViewController = container;
        [app.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [navigationController.menuContainerViewController
             toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
        });
    } else {
        [navigationController.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you tried with **UIStatusBarStyleLightContent**

Comment: Yes, I tried that too to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass MFSideMenuContainerViewController and add `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` method to the new class.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to make Black Status Bar with White Text in one of my app, and i just want to make things simpler and easy ..... :) :p

So what i did is, just make a desired background Image with 20 pixel black strip at the top of the Image.

set this image in app Background

and call this method in **ViewControllers**

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

thats all and i got the Black Status Bar with White Text.

Comment: Are you using MFSideMenu?